# CSV形式でデータフレームを読み込み、特定のカラムを抽出して新しいデータフレームを作成したい

Tags: python, csv

各社のCSVデータをfor文で読み込み、必要なカラムだけ抽出して新たなデータフレームを作成したいと考えております。
ファイル読込み後、添付画像のようにA，Bの売上を抽出して、新たなデータフレームを作成するにはどのようにすればよろしいでしょうか。（稀に売上データに欠損値がある場合もございます。）

ご教示のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
# ファイル指定
outfolder = '...r/'
#loopでデータ読込したい（ID(10と20)はdataというデータフレームで保持している）
for index, id in enumerate(data['ID'].unique()):
    #フォルダ＋ファイル名（list10_0.5h,list20_0.5h）で読込
    df =(pd.read_csv(outfolder + str('list') + str(id) + '_0.5h.csv', usecols=[3])
```

**A社の売上データ**

[image: A社の売上データ]

**B社の売上データ**

[image: B社の売上データ]

**A社とB社の売上データを抽出して新しいデータフレームを作成したい**

[image: A社とB社の売上データを抽出して新しいデータフレームを作成したい]

Answer (score 0):

「稀に売上データに欠損値がある場合」が、例えばある会社は2017/02分の1行が抜けていることがある、という意味であれば、最初に対象の月の`DataFrame`をつくっておいて、そこに1社ずつマージしていけばいいと思います。

```py
# ファイル指定
outfolder = '...r/'
df_base = DataFrame({
  '月': ['2017/01','2017/02','2017/03','2017/04','2017/05','2017/06','2017/07','2017/08','2017/09','2017/10']
})
#loopでデータ読込したい（ID(10と20)はdataというデータフレームで保持している）
for index, id in enumerate(data['ID'].unique()):
    #フォルダ＋ファイル名（list10_0.5h,list20_0.5h）で読込
    df =(pd.read_csv(outfolder + str('list') + str(id) + '_0.5h.csv', usecols=[3])
    tmp_df = df[['月', '売上']]
    df_base = pd.merge(df_base, tmp_df, on='月', how='left')
    df_base = df_base.rename(columns={'売上': df['name'].unique()[0]})
```

※質問のコードを見ると、現状全く処理を実装されていないように見えます。それでは他の人に実装を依頼していることになってしまうので、「このように実装したけど、こういう部分でうまく動かない」というような質問をされた方がよりよいかなぁと思います。

Comment: ご忠告いただきありがとうございます。また親切にご対応いただき、重ねて御礼申し上げます。大変助かりました。
以後、質問の仕方について改善してまいります。

Answer (score 0):

全ての CSV ファイルを読み込んで単一のデータフレームに格納した後、`pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` で企業別に分割します。次に、分割したデータフレームを「月」をキーにして outer join(`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`) します。そのため、欠損値は `NaN` になります。

```py
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 20]})
outfolder = '...r/'

dfs = reduce(
  lambda l, r: pd.merge(l, r, how='outer', on='月'),
  pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(f'{outfolder}list{id}_0.5h.csv',
      parse_dates=['月'], thousands=',')
    for id in data.ID.unique()])
  .groupby('name')
  .pipe(lambda grp: [
    g[['月', '売上']].rename(columns={'売上': k})
    for k, g in grp
  ])
)

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(dfs)

=>
# B社 2017/6/1 の売上データがない(欠損)

          月          A        B
0 2017-01-01   9786.351   6459.0
1 2017-02-01   8464.354   5586.0
2 2017-03-01  20291.400  13392.0
3 2017-04-01  13129.610   8666.0
4 2017-05-01  33974.490  22423.0
5 2017-06-01  36048.030      NaN
6 2017-07-01  48785.010  32198.0
7 2017-08-01  12199.740   8052.0
8 2017-09-01   6442.446   4252.0
9 2017-10-01  47193.700  31148.0
```

Comment: 丁寧に解説いただきありがとうございます。
こちらのコードを参考に勉強させていただきます。